# Redis KeyExists then GetValue Optimization

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm new to using Redis and have written my c# block to be:

```
public string GetValue(string key) 
{
    if (IDatabase.KeyExists(key))
    {
        return IDatabase.StringGet(key);
    }
    else 
    {
        //Get value from SQL, put it into Redis, then return it
    }
}
```

My question is, how inefficient is it that I am first checking Redis for existance of the key, and then asking Redis a second time for the value of that key? Essentially I'm making two trips to Redis here and I want to know if that's negligible given Redis' speed, or is that something I should try to change in my repo layer so that only a single trip to Redis gets made?

Comment: Please provide what library you're currently using to work with Redis... (add a tag!)

Comment: You should also worry about correctness, what if the key got removed from redis between your KeyExists and StringGet?

Comment: @Lukazoid I believe this is hard to solve... At the end of the day, OP is talking about caching... I mean, if this happens, who cares... A concrete client will show some outdated data. Next time that client will receive the updated one...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your answer solves this problem doesn't it? By making the retrieval of the value atomic. The issue I was concerned with was when the value is evicted from redis, the askers code would return a `null` value which would be completely wrong.

Comment: @Lukazoid Yeah, haha. You're right. BTW I was thinking about the initial code provided by the OP

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually Redis throws errors for very edge cases, and trying to get a string key value using *StackExchange.Redis* won't throw an exception if the key doesn't exist.

Since you're using *StackExchange.Redis* to work with Redis, when you call `IDatabase.GetString` the return value is a `RedisValue` (it's a `struct`! it can't be null excepting if it's turned into a nullable type), which has a `HasValue` property.

That is, you should get the Redis string as `RedisValue` (don't cast it to `string` directly). Your code should look like this:

```
public string GetValue(string key) 
{
    RedisValue value = _cacheRepo.GetString(key);

    // You might also use !value.IsNullOrEmpty
    if (!value.IsNull)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else 
    {
        //Get value from SQL, put it into Redis, then return it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Does HasValue (or !value.IsNullOrEmpty) differentiate between the Key not existing versus the value of the Key being empty/null?

Comment: @JBStevens6 HasValue/IsNullOrEmpty are sending no command to Redis, this is the main difference

Comment: Note that HasValue being equivalent to !value.IsNullOrEmpty means a key with an empty value will be treated the same as a missing key. If you want to know when the key exists, regardless of emptiness, you should use !value.IsNull instead.